# MultiPart Data in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Can anyone help me to know:
How to send text and image type data through multipart data form in javascript to my api. Please help me in getting the solution of my question.

```
function apiCall(url){
        var myJsonObj ;

        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
        {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
            }
            else
            {// code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            xmlhttp.open("POST",url,true);
            xmlhttp.send();
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
            {
                if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
                {

                // document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
                myJsonObj = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText); 
                  if(myJsonObj.SS == "TRUE"){
                      window.location = "index.jsp";
                  }


                }
            }
        }
```

This set of code is not working for sending  Multipart data.

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SO. Please provide some code.

Comment: You could use a hidden form that posts to a hidden iFrame. Or you could encode the image as base64 and just send it as a normal variable.

Answer (score 1):

What about `xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");` somewhere between open() and send(data)?

Answer (score 1):

I have solved the issue of multipart this way:

```
function senddata() {

    var boundary = generateBoundary();

    var url =   "http://localhost:8084/MagicFolder/enterProductDetails?";
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest;

    xhr.open("POST", url, true);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
    alert("Your Response is:" +xhr.responseText);
    }
    };
    var contentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary;
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", contentType);

   // for (var header in this.headers) {
   // xhr.setRequestHeader(header, headers[header]);
   // }

    // here's our data variable that we talked about earlier

    var data =buildMessage(getelements(), boundary);
     alert("Your Final Data is" +data);
    // finally send the request as binary data
    xhr.sendAsBinary(data);
    }

    function getelements() {
        var fields = [];

        // gather INPUT elements
        var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
        for (var l=inputs.length, i=0; i<l;i++){
         fields.push(inputs[i]);

        }

        // gather SELECT elements
        var selects = document.getElementsByTagName("SELECT");
        for (var l=selects.length, i=0; i<l;i++){
            fields.push(selects[i]);
        }

        return fields;
    }


    function generateBoundary() {
     // alert("AJAX-----------------------" + (new Date).getTime());
    //  genboundary= "AJAX-----------------------" + (new Date).getTime();
    //  alert(genboundary);
   // return "AJAX-----------------------" + (new Date).getTime());
      return ("AJAX-----------------------");
    }



   function buildMessage(getelements, boundary) {

       //alert("helllloooooooooooooooooooojjjjjjjjjjj"+getelements);
    var CRLF = "\r\n";
    var parts = [];
  // alert(getelements());
    getelements.forEach(function(element, index, all) {

    var part = "";
    var type = "TEXT";

    if (element.nodeName.toUpperCase() === "INPUT") {
    type = element.getAttribute("type").toUpperCase();
    }

    if (type === "FILE" && element.files.length > 0) {
    var fieldName = element.name;
    var fileName = element.files[0].fileName;

    /*
    * Content-Disposition header contains name of the field
    * used to upload the file and also the name of the file as
    * it was on the user's computer.
    */
    part += 'Content-Disposition: form-data; ';
    part += 'name="' + fieldName + '"; ';
    part += 'filename="'+ fileName + '"' + CRLF;

    /*
    * Content-Type header contains the mime-type of the file
    * to send. Although we could build a map of mime-types
    * that match certain file extensions, we'll take the easy
    * approach and send a general binary header:
    * application/octet-stream
    */
    part += "Content-Type: application/octet-stream";
    part += CRLF + CRLF; // marks end of the headers part

    /*
    * File contents read as binary data, obviously
    */
    part += element.files[0].getAsBinary() + CRLF;
    } else {
    /*
    * In case of non-files fields, Content-Disposition
    * contains only the name of the field holding the data.
    */
        if (element.nodeName.toUpperCase() === "INPUT") {
            type = element.getAttribute("type").toUpperCase();
        }

         if (type === "TEXT" || type==="SELECT") {

            part += 'Content-Disposition: form-data; ';
            part += 'name="' + element.name + '"' + CRLF + CRLF;

            /*
            * Field value
            */
            part += element.value + CRLF;
        }
   }   
    parts.push(part);
    });

    var request = "--" + boundary + CRLF;
    request+= parts.join("--" + boundary + CRLF);
    request+= "--" + boundary + "--" + CRLF;

    return request;
    }


  Note: This set of code works fine for the multipart data.
```